# Gdb on raspbian libc function names

Tags: c, arm, gdb, raspbian

I'm having some issues when using gdb on a raspberry pi 3

On raspbian it doesn't show libc function names.

If I define a function the disassembly shows `bl my_func`.

For libc functions - `puts("test")` - it shows something like `bl  0x12345`

I have the latest version of libc6-dbg installed.

Should I install other libraries? Am I doing something wrong?

As a side note, I've also tried ubuntu mate - gdb shows proper function names for libc functions, however it crashes with a segfault when running the binary; I found this thread regarding this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb/+bug/1576432

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS seems to work ok - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think address resolution for PLT stubs is just not implemented in upstream gdb/BFD.  I found this discussion:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/LnweJJORhZI

And the patch has not been applied.  Perhaps Ubuntu is carrying it as a private patch?